# Extend the window.top through ts type, improve vscode tips

Tags: typescript

The old project is developed using `iframe`. There are many private attributes on the top-level window, and other pages communicate through top. Now I want to extend the top type in the iframe page through ts. how can I change the following code to avoid errors

```
interface TopWindow extends Window {
    createMP: (key?: string) => CustomPlayer;
}

declare var top: TopWindow | null;
```

The above code will cause an ts(2403) error

Answer (score 0):

Because of [interface merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces), you could actually use this:

```
interface Window {
    createMP: (key?: string) => CustomPlayer;
}

top!.createMP // ok
```

Subsequent definitions of the `Window` interface are merged into the "original".

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQ3L1m)